# Dispatcher and collection bound to the UI

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

Annoyance of the Dispatcher and hopefully some know the ways around it.

Issue:
Any UI element or anything binding to them are **FORCED/Required** onto the Dispatcher thread.
Which then results in hang time depending on the operation.
I for one have a collection bound to an UI element and the operations onto cannot be on a different thread so hang time is imminent.

Any solution to this problem ?

Please, do not reply with `Dispatcher.Invoke` or any related type as they do not work. Because they are synchronous. Right now, all I can really do is optimize the operation to go as fast as possible but really limited.

Comment: Could you please provide some additional details as to the specific issue (e.g. code sample, etc.)?  If you are updating the UI there is really no way around using the UI thread.

Comment: @rmayer06, It's just retrieving some data to a collection and having it bound to a ListView. It is being changed right now as I test random stuff, so it is messy until I get the gist of my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that, while some of the work that you're doing needs to be in the UI thread, that *all* of it doesn't.  If you're binding data to a control you should ensure that the data is all computed in a background thread, and then the only action taking place in the UI thread is applying already fetched/computed data to controls.  As an example, if you are using an `IQueryable` framework and you bind the result of an `IQueryable` query as a data source, then the results of that query haven't actually been evaluated yet; the database hasn't actually been queried as the results have not been iterated.  Doing this would result in the UI thread making a database call, which is a bad thing.  In such an example it would be best to pull the query results into a List and then bind the list in the UI thread.

If you actually have so much data that it really takes you a long time to update all of the controls despite the fact that you *aren't* doing anything like what I have described, then you may need to more fundamentally re-design your application.  If this is really the case for you then you must be binding many thousands of rows of data to a DataGrid (or something along those lines).  You may need to paginate the data, or do something else along those lines to ensure that that much data isn't actually applied to your control all at once.  You need to find some way of breaking things up into smaller chunks of data, and then displaying those smaller chunks of data.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about doing all the work on a different thread and then just transfer the collection over but it was just unpleasant doing that or looked extra work for my lazy bum so I wasted days figuring some other solution. Hoping someone comes with some crazy tactic to handle this.

Comment: @RezaM. There may very well be easier ways of doing some work in a background thread and some in the UI thread.  (It's hard, without seeing your code, to know if you're using an overly complex method or not.)  In general the code doesn't need to be *that* complex (for the easy cases).  It will also depend on your version of C#; newer versions have done a lot to make these types of actions easier.

Comment: @RezaM.  I would suggest using a `BackgroundWorker`.  You can do all of the non-UI work in the `DoWork` method, and then update the `UI` with the results in the `WorkerCompleted` event (which will automatically be marshaled to the UI thread for you).  Or, if you're on .NET 4.5 already, you can use Async/await to make this even simpler.

Comment: yeah, I know, the code ain't complex. Just... I was being hard headed. and yes, I'll use WorkerComplete in the end but want to see if anyone comes out with a solution for a bit. In a couple hours, I'll mark your answer as the chosen one if no one answers. Thanks.

Comment: You're not going to find a better solution.  You need to execute the UI task in the UI thread and the long running non-UI task in a background thread.  There may or may not be more convenient means of doing that, but it still needs to be done.  Without knowing what you *currently* have we can't know if it's a convenient way or not.

Comment: Yes, if I follow the discussion correctly I agree with @Servy.  You need to do the retrieving on a background thread (perhaps using Task.Factory.StartNew()), then call Dispatcher.Invoke from that thread once the items have loaded.